# SQL date string split

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

How could I split a date range like this

> 20120301-20120331

into two different dates in T-SQL? The data appears in a column called date_range.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the column type is VARCHAR? Is the format always consistent (i.e. every date is in the format YYYYMMDD, and the two dates are always separated by exactly one dash, with no internal whitespace?)

Comment: Yes it is always consistent and is a VARCHAR. Thanks!

Comment: One option I can think of is too use the '-' as a delimiter, and then perform the split function. But I will prefer a more efficient way to do this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(17) = '20120301-20120331';

SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@string, 8)), 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(@string, 8));
```

From a table:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(column_name, 8)),
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(column_name, 8))
FROM dbo.table_name;
```

Comment: This will not work as I need to do it over the whole table and not just one single row. :(

Comment: @OBL - Just replace `@string` with the column of your table, and add an   `FROM YourTable` after the select

Comment: The @variable was just for a demo. If you want code that you don't have to do any work at all to make work, it is a good idea to specify in the question the table and column names you're talking about (in addition to whether you're talking about SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc).